# Module view base folder in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, view

What is the purpose of the view/base in magento2 modules ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This area is common for *adminhtml* and *frontend* areas. For example: you have styles and scripts files which are identical for frontend and backend. You can place them in *base* area folder to avoid copy-paste.

Comment: How would you extend an xml file sourcing from base affecting only frontend output? (from app/..) ??

Answer (score 3):

The base folder is an area to share for client side resources (less, js, images, etc.), layouts, templates, etc., between the frontend and adminhtml areas. For example, if you want to use the same js library between the frontend and adminhtml area, you would put it in view/base/web/js/lib/your-library.js. If you were to add that library to the frontend directory, it would not be accessible from adminhtml and vice versa.