# Use or purpose of magento2-base folder in vendor/magento

Tags: magento2, vendor

Can anyone please let me know what's the use of **magento2-base folder under vendor/magento directory**? Most of the time, some search results show the error message obtained from this directory.

Note : I want to know **magento2-base folder under vendor/magento directory** and not the *view base area of working like adminhtml and frontend*.

What's the actual purpose of **magento2-base folder under vendor/magento directory**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module view base folder in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96719/module-view-base-folder-in-magento2)

Comment: @magefms No buddy. I have edited the question.